# Get Average amount of Months between sales in each row in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Name         Customer   StockCode       Description         3/01/2013   4/01/2013   5/01/2013   6/01/2013   7/01/2013   8/01/2013   9/01/2013   10/01/2013  11/01/2013  12/01/2013  1/01/2014   2/01/2014   3/01/2014   4/01/2014   5/01/2014   6/01/2014   7/01/2014   8/01/2014   9/01/2014   10/01/2014  11/01/2014  12/01/2014  1/01/2015   2/01/2015   3/01/2015
AAG Ice Cream   564     243702  4/1 Gal Ja-Rtu Pineapple    NULL    NULL    NULL    274.40  NULL    NULL    313.60  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    392.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
AAG Ice Cream   564     243701  4/1 Gal Ja-Rtu Strawberry   NULL    NULL    NULL    660.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    660.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    660.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
AAG Ice Cream   564     248050  4/1 Gal-RTU Choc Syrup      NULL    NULL    NULL    534.00  NULL    NULL    534.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    534.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I need to determine the average amount of months between sales per row. So if I have 3 nulls then a sale and then 4 nulls and then a sale and then 4 nulls and a sale on a row I can come up with 3.6 months(4 Rounded) on average that this customer buy an item during the last 24 months.So if I see 5 Month elapse from today without a sale I can flag the customer on that row.(Customer/StockCode combo.)

Other style -  Direct query no pivot.

```
SELECT Customer,StockCode,SUM(InvoiceValue) as Amount ,MONTH(TrnDate) as        [Month],YEAR(TrnDate) as [Year]
 FROM ArSalesMove
  WHERE TrnDate BETWEEN  DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate())   AND  GETDATE()
  GROUP BY Customer,StockCode,MONTH(TrnDate),YEAR(TrnDate)
  ORDER BY Customer,StockCode,YEAR(TrnDate),MONTH(TrnDate)
```

```
Customer StockCode      Amount  Month   Year
0000023 850802          3542.40  5  2013
0000023 850802          0        6  2013
0000023 850802          0        7  2013
0000023 850802          0        8  2013
0000023 850802          2361.60  9  2013
0000023 850802          0        10 2013
0000023 850802          0        11 2013
0000023 850802          0        12 2013
0000023 850802          2361.60   1 2014
0000023 850802          0         2 2014
0000023 850802          0         3 2014
0000023 850802          0         4 2014
0000023 850802          4723.20   5 2014
0000023 850802          0         6 2014
0000023 850802          0         7 2014
0000023 850802          3542.40   8 2014
0000023 850802          0         9 2014
0000023 850802          0        10 2014
0000023 850802          0        11 2014
0000023 850802          2361.60  12 2014
0000023 850802          0         1 2015
0000023 850802          0         2 2015
0000023 850802          0         3 2015
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArSalesMove](
[Customer] [char](7) NOT NULL,
[TrnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Register] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
[SummaryLine] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
[DetailLine] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
[Invoice] [char](6) NULL,
[StockCode] [char](30) NULL,
[Warehouse] [char](2) NULL,
[InvoiceQty] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
[InvoiceValue] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[CostValue] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[DocumentType] [char](1) NULL,
[Branch] [char](2) NULL,
[Salesperson] [char](3) NULL,
[Bin] [char](6) NULL,
[OrderType] [char](2) NULL,
[Area] [char](2) NULL,
[ProductClass] [char](4) NULL,
[TaxCode] [char](1) NULL,
[TaxValue] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[DiscValue] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[TaxCodeFst] [char](1) NULL,
[TaxValueFst] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[SalesOrder] [char](6) NULL,
[CustomerPoNumber] [char](30) NULL,
[TrnYear] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
[TrnMonth] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
[ForInvoiceValue] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
[InvoiceCurrency] [char](3) NULL,
[SalesOrderLine] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
[TimeStamp] [timestamp] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [ArSalesMoveKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Customer] ASC,
  [TrnDate] ASC,
  [Register] ASC,
  [SummaryLine] ASC,
  [DetailLine] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Why is your data stored this way?

Comment: What I did is create a temp table with this data by using a pivot.

Comment: After we solve this, I'll then have to figure how to do it with dynamically created column names.

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL Server, there might be a much easier way to do this and *without* using temp tables and pivots.

Comment: The version is SQL 2008

Comment: I did not get your question.. can you explain again - Did you mean total month between 2 sale values divided by 2 or explain how you come up with 3.6 in above example.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the actual table? I think it may be easier to get to the desired result like Aaron Bertrand suggested.

Comment: Aaron see posted table structure

Comment: make a tri annual (4 months) group and take average

Answer (score 0):

What I did was Create a GroupID field, Then I populated it with a value where the InvoiceValue what not equal to 0:

```
 SET @counter = 0
 UPDATE @tempSales 
 SET @counter = tt.GroupID = @counter + 1
 FROM @tempSales  tt
 WHERE  CASE WHEN tt.InvoiceValue <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```

That left me with NULL values where the InvoiceValue was NULL so I back filled the Null:

```
 SELECT t1.ID,t1.TrnDate, t1.Customer,t1.StockCode,t1.InvoiceValue,
(--Fill Back null Values...
SELECT t2.GroupID
FROM @tempSales t2
WHERE t2.ID = (
    SELECT MAX(t3.ID)
    FROM @tempSales t3
    WHERE t3.ID <= t1.ID
    AND GroupID IS NOT NULL
   )
 ) AS GroupID
FROM @tempSales t1
```

Next I Counted the GroupID and Group BY GroupID.

Then I got an average of the Counts and then Date of Last sale MAX(TrnDate), and created a flag for Customer/StockCode combinations that exceed the average months between sales.

```
  CASE WHEN MonthsSinceLastSale > ZeroAvg + 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Flag -
```

And here it all is in a Stored Procedure...

```
ALTER PROC GetZeroMonthsReport
@Customer Varchar(50),
@StockCode Varchar(50)

as

DECLARE @tempSales TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    TrnDate DATETIME, Customer NVARCHAR(50),StockCode NVARCHAR(50), InvoiceValue      decimal, GroupID INT)
DECLARE @temp  TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, TrnDate   DATETIME, Customer NVARCHAR(50),StockCode NVARCHAR(50), InvoiceValue decimal,   GroupID INT)
DECLARE @counter int


INSERT INTO @temp (TrnDate, Customer,StockCode, InvoiceValue)
Select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MONTH(TrnDate)) + '/01/' +   CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Year(TrnDate)) as TrnDate ,  RTRIM(Customer),RTRIM(StockCode), SUM(InvoiceValue)
FROM dbo.ArSalesMove s WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE TrnDate BETWEEN  DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate())   AND  GETDATE()
AND RTRIM(Customer)+RTRIM(StockCode) NOT IN ( SELECT   RTRIM(Customer)+RTRIM(StockCode) FROM dbo.ArSalesExclusion a WITH(NOLOCK))
 AND RTRIM(Customer)<>'999'
 AND RTRIM(StockCode)<>'704033'--Wood Pallets    
 AND RTRIM(Customer)IN (SELECT DISTINCT  RTRIM(Customer) From ArSalesMove   WHERE TrnDate Between DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate())   AND  GETDATE())
 AND RTRIM(StockCode)IN (SELECT DISTINCT  RTRIM(StockCode) From ArSalesMove  WHERE TrnDate Between DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate())   AND  GETDATE())
 GROUP BY Customer,StockCode,MONTH(TrnDate),Year(TrnDate)
 ORDER BY Customer,StockCode,TrnDate
;WITH enum AS 
(
Select Customer,StockCode, StartDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MONTH(DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate()) )) + '/01/' +   CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Year(DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GetDate()) ))), --  MIN(TrnDate), 
 EndDate = GETDATE()-- MAX(TrnDate)
 FROM @temp

  Group BY Customer,StockCode 

  UNION ALL

SELECT Customer,StockCode, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, StartDate), EndDate
FROM enum 
WHERE StartDate < EndDate   
) 

INSERT INTO @tempSales (TrnDate, Customer,StockCode,InvoiceValue,GroupID)
SELECT  
e.StartDate,
e.Customer, 
e.StockCode,
InvoiceValue = ISNULL(t.InvoiceValue, 0), GroupID
FROM enum e
LEFT JOIN  @temp t ON  e.StartDate = t.TrnDate AND   e.StockCode =       t.StockCode AND e.Customer = t.Customer
ORDER BY e.Customer,e.StockCode,  e.StartDate

SET @counter = 0
UPDATE @tempSales 
SET @counter = tt.GroupID = @counter + 1
FROM @tempSales  tt
WHERE  CASE WHEN tt.InvoiceValue <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1

SELECT (Select Name From ArCustomer Where RTRIM(Customer) = d.Customer) as    Name,
d.Customer,d.StockCode,
(Select [Description] From InvMaster Where RTRIM(StockCode) = d.StockCode)   as [Description],
d.LastSaleDate,d.MonthsSinceLastSale,d.ZeroAvg,d.Flag  FROM (
SELECT   c.Customer,c.StockCode,c.LastSaleDate,c.MonthsSinceLastSale,c.ZeroAvg,c.Flag 
FROM (
SELECT   b.Customer,b.StockCode,b.LastSaleDate,b.MonthsSinceLastSale,b.ZeroAvg,CASE WHEN    MonthsSinceLastSale > ZeroAvg + 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Flag --Add one month  cusion..
FROM (
SELECT a.Customer,a.StockCode,
 AVG(a.ZeroCount) as ZeroAvg,
(SELECT COUNT(TrnDate) as MonthsSinceLastSale FROM @tempSales
 WHERE Customer = a.Customer AND StockCode = a.StockCode AND  TrnDate   BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(TrnDate) FROM @tempSales tt WHERE Customer = a.Customer AND    StockCode = a.StockCode AND InvoiceValue <> 0)  AND GETDATE()) as   MonthsSinceLastSale,
 (SELECT MAX(TrnDate) FROM @tempSales tt WHERE Customer = a.Customer AND    StockCode = a.StockCode AND  InvoiceValue<> 0) as LastSaleDate
 FROM (
 Select COUNT(z.GroupID) as ZeroCount,z.Customer,z.StockCode,z.GroupID 
 FROM (

 SELECT  x.ID,x.TrnDate,    x.Customer,x.StockCode,x.InvoiceValue,ISNULL(x.GroupID,0) as GroupID
 FROM (
 SELECT t1.ID,t1.TrnDate, t1.Customer,t1.StockCode,t1.InvoiceValue,
 (--Fill Back null Values...
  SELECT t2.GroupID
  FROM @tempSales t2
  WHERE t2.ID = (
    SELECT MAX(t3.ID)
    FROM @tempSales t3
    WHERE t3.ID <= t1.ID
    AND GroupID IS NOT NULL
   )
  ) AS GroupID
 FROM @tempSales t1
 ) as x
 ) as z

 WHERE z.InvoiceValue = 0
 GROUP BY z.GroupID,z.Customer,z.StockCode
  ) as a
  GROUP BY  Customer,StockCode
  ) as b
  WHERE b.LastSaleDate IS NOT NULL
  ) as c
  Where c.Flag = 1
  ) as d 
 ORDER BY d.Customer,d.StockCode
```